# Drupal 7: How to copy value of fields to another field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to convert the fieldtype of existing fields to another. A possible solution I thought of is to copy an existing field to a new field.

Does [the method using VBO](http://drupal.org/node/1000200) work in Drupal 7?
How do I do the same for the file/image field with multiple entries in Drupal 7?

Comment: Is the existing field you want to copy part of a node? Then the next question is, are you making a custom form that you want to use the field from a node? Then lastly, what do you want to do with the image? Answering those should help get some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a module for that, http://drupal.org/project/node_convert .  It may work for you!